# Xamarin Forms PCL Socket plugin is not receiving data from the wifi card

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have the need to connect Xamarin forms pcl, or both ios that Android devices with a built-in wifi card, with tcp client.
The fact is that the connection is made, the writing as well, but I can not read data that come back to me.
I usually work with serial, I would not want it to be for the time-out that I can not read through tcp.

Can anyone give me some advice, I will mean little.
I am using this plugin Xamarin forms pcl to connect.

Or if anyone has any other solutions, please, tell me. I wanted to directly use the Socket, but I can not enter the library Systems.Net.Socket in visual studio.

```
private async void testTCPSocketPlugin()
    {
        int port = 5555;
        String ip = "192.168.222.1";

        TcpSocketListener listener = new TcpSocketListener();

        await listener.StartListeningAsync(5555);
        listener.ConnectionReceived += Listener_ConnectionReceived;

        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(ip, port);

            //listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
            //{
            //    var clientListener = args.SocketClient;

            //    var bytesRead = -1;
            //    var buf = new byte[1];

            //    while (bytesRead != 0)
            //    {
            //        bytesRead = await args.SocketClient.ReadStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, 1);
            //        if (bytesRead > 0)
            //        {

            //        }
            //        //Debug.Write(buf[0]);
            //    }
            //};
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        //byte[] array1 = null;
        Byte[] dati = new Byte[8];
        dati[0] = 1;
        dati[1] = 8;
        dati[2] = 0;
        dati[3] = 0;
        dati[4] = 0;
        dati[5] = 0;
        dati[6] = 0xe0;
        dati[7] = 0x0b;

        Byte[] fromBoard = new Byte[8];

        try
        {
            await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(dati, 0, 8);

            client.ReadStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;

            Stream str = client.ReadStream;
            int testInt = await client.ReadStream.ReadAsync(fromBoard, 0, 8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void Listener_ConnectionReceived(object sender, Sockets.Plugin.Abstractions.TcpSocketListenerConnectEventArgs e)
    {
        String test = "break here";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are some wrong things in your code, I will try to point all of them.

First, you're mixing the client and the server code in one function and that's extremely confusing, even if that's just a test, so first of all separate the code in two functions, it will be a lot more readable.

Second, your client tries to connect and write before the server is listening:

```
    try
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    //...

        await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(dati, 0, 8);

        await listener.StartListeningAsync(5555);
```

That will make the connection to fail, before you start the client the server must be listening. You state the connection is made, but I doubt it unless you execute the call twice and the second time it will work if the previous server remains listening.

Next, you call to `await listener.StartListeningAsync(5555);` before hooking the event, it's not extremely harmful but if for some reason the client is trying to connect at the moment the server boots up then probably that connection will be lost as it will be accepted before nothing is attached to the event handler.

After that, you try to read from the client stream, but the server isn't sending anything, so the code will block at `int testInt = await client.ReadStream.ReadAsync(fromBoard, 0, 8);` until it throws a read exception because it will reach the timeout.

Finally, if you prefer a pure native solution you can create the client/server code on a shared library, reference that library on the iOS/Android projects, create a DependencyService on these projects and then retrieve the service on the PCL library, this way you can have the full control of the code.

UPDATE:

It seems that you're not using at all any of the server functions, try this:

```
async void Call()
{
    TcpSocketClient client = new TcpSocketClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync("192.168.222.1", 5555);

    byte[] Data = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xe0, 0x0b }

    await client.WriteStream.WriteAsync(Data, 0, 8);
    byte[] finalData = new byte[8];
    int read = await client.ReadStream.ReadAsync(finalData, 0, 8);

    //Check here, read will have the number of bytes read.
}
```

Don't add any try/catch and if any exception is thrown update the question.

Comment: I tried to change the code according to your instructions, but the listener does not seem as ever.
There is no way to solve?

Comment: Does not seem what? does not seem to connect? does not seem to receive anything? Put the client and the server code and be more explicit with the problem please.

Comment: It does not seem to be able to pick up the reading, however, the writing and the connection works

Comment: You aren't writing anything at the server side, so the client will never read anything...

Comment: With the company for me, we have a logic board that just is written, she responds with a buffer immediately.
Then just launch the write, she replies, I can not pick up the reading.
I also say that already have software in desktop WPF work. I only have problems with Xamarin reading.

Comment: If you've posted a different code than the one you're using then there's no way to help you.

Comment: Also, if you feel more comfortable with TcpListener or Socket then read my explanation on how to use a DependencyService.

Comment: Maybe I explained bad, I said the same card works with the desktop WPF software, I'll tell you just to make you understand that the card works, is the code I am using it wrong. I now, with the above code, I do with the app and query the tcp, reading and writing. But I can not read.

Comment: So, again, you're posting a server code which isn't being used and a client code which differs from the real one, so unless you post the real code (the client one) there's no way to help you as the code you posted is not the same you're testing.

Comment: The firmware can not share..but not needed because the WPF work..and return an array of bytes. Not only it works on Xamarin. But thanks anyway for the help

Comment: No, you don't get it, I mean you must post the REAL Xamarin code, not the code at the server.

Comment: what I put in the answer is the code Xamarin forms pcl

Comment: Then if the server is on a device why the code is also trying to create a TcpSocketListener? You only need to create the client part, not the server one.

Comment: I need the device, ios or android, both, you connettato IP I say, that they read, and write a byte buffer.

Comment: Then there's no TcpSocketListener involved at all, that's like a regular TcpListener and it's used to receive incomming connections, you can remove completely that part of the code as it does nothing.

Comment: i don't know but...if i change await client.ReadStream.ReadAsync(fromBoard, 0, 8); to await client.ReadStream.Read(fromBoard, 0, 8); works. thanks anyway for help

Comment: evidently with the active async, lost time, removing await and leaving the synchronous method immediately collects the answer.